# -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html-email

I'm creating an html esignature. Despite the same styles being applied to all of the text there is still ONE line of text the the iPhone keeps enlarging. I've read that -webikit-text-size-adjust: none; should prevent this but it is not working. Here is my code for this particular table cell.

```
<td valign="bottom" class="tag" style="display: block; width: 280px; height: 18px; padding-right: 6px; padding-top: 2px; text-align: right;">
<a style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; line-height: 20px; font-weight: 500; color:#585859; white-space: nowrap; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">branding <span style="color: #db1e17;">|</span> communications <span style="color: #db1e17;">|</span> interactive</a>
</td>
```

In my media query above specifically for iPhone my code is this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-height: 320px), screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 480px){ 
td.tag {
width: 136px !important;
height: 7px !important;
padding-top: 2px !important;
padding-right: 3px !important;  
}

td.tag a{
font-size: 5px !important;
line-height: 9px !important;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
```

Can you see what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried taking it out of your media query?

Answer (score 0):

I would put this outside of the media query.

```
div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
```

All you are doing at this point is telling the phone to never set the minimum font-size for all elements.